# django - how to post array of images to views

Tags: python, html, django, http, post

i am stuck on this issue since yesterday. i have a form where user can select more image files and submit. now i am not able to catch those `POSTED` image files in my views.py.

my html:

`<input type="file" name="images[]" />`
`<input type="file" name="images[]" />`

and in my views.py i did this:

`images = request.POST.getlist('images[]')`

but once i `print images`, i am getting `[]`, empty array. what am i doing wrong? i want to get all selected image files and save them into db in my view.

**EDIT:**
this is my html:

```
<form action="/save/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
 <input type="file" name="images[]" /> 
 <input type="file" name="images[]" />
<input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

this is my views.py

```
fotos = request.POST.getlist('images[]')
for i in range(len(fotos)):
  print fotos[i]
```

here it is printing `[]`, and not the names of each images. why is this array empty?

thanks for help.

Comment: Can you post some more code from your html and views.py to show the form & the collection of the post in the view?

Answer (score 3):

When Django handles a file upload, it's a little different than a regular POST field. The data is place in `request.FILES` and needs to be accessed there. [The documentation about handling file uploads is a great starting point.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/)

Comment: thanks, so can you pls show me how i get those files in my views.py

Comment: @doniyor: please point your url at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/ as Liv suggested.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, i dont see anything there which is relevant to my question. e.g.: **how to handle array of posted images in the view**

Comment: The `images[]` scheme is something that's PHP-specific and doesn't have any special meaning elsewhere (in other words, Python/Django don't interpret that as an array). So if you want to upload multiple images, you'll have to create separate file fields with unique names for your form, ex. "image1" and "image2". Then, you can manipulate the data in those files by accessing `request.FILES['image1']` and `request.FILES['image2']`.

Comment: That docs page has everything you need, then you just need to display the form in the template as normal; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#displaying-a-form-using-a-template